# Let's Encrypt NET::ERR_CERT_INVALID

Tags: https, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to setup HTTPS to some of my company's web services.

Currently I have several web services sharing the same public ip address proxied by a firewall (all allowing both 80 and 443):

- web1.company.net
- web2.company.net
- web3.company.net
- and so on...

I have SSH access to these VMs only when connected to the company's VPN.

I tried setting up let's encrypt with auto renewal with 2 different docker images (and both are giving the same "error"):

- jwilder/nginx-proxy + jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
- https-portal

After completing the setup, if I'm connected to the VPN, the HTTPS works perfectly (I basically see the closed lock next to the link).

Whenever I disconnect the VPN connection and test the same website I get the following:

[image]

I also tried to check the certificate chains.

When I'm connected to the VPN I get the correct certificate chain:

[image: WORKING]

When I'm not connected to the VPN  I believe, I don't:

[image: NOT WORKING]

Any clue on what can cause this? Maybe the firewall doesn't know how to proxy the request because part of what it needs is encrypted and it doesn't know how to decrypt it? I'm a total newbie in this.

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Who do you use for DNS?

Comment: @CoolAJ86 a small Italian company called Omniaweb

Comment: Your Firewall will have the SNI header from the TLS hello packet that's the beginning of every HTTPS connection. However, it may be that your "firewall" is actually a load balancer with an "ssl accelerator".

What's the goal that you need to accomplish? You want to make this site public from an on-prem local server?

Comment: I'll give soon a more specific definition on what the "firewall" actually is but yes exactly. Basically we don't have enough public ips so based on the url the firewall will redirect the request to the correct internal VM.

Comment: It sounds like you need to figure out how to get your firewall to do SNI Routing. That may be more of a "ServerFault" question than a "StackOverflow" question.